# Storing key, value pairs with redis sorted set

Tags: hash, redis, hashtable, sortedset

I want to store (key, value) pairs in a Redis sorted set (along with the double for ordering). My current option would be to have the sorted set for the keys, and then have another Redis hash that I can store the pairs in. Is there a better/more canonical way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It highly depends on the planned use of the sorted set. One pattern you *might* use is to duplicate the data.  As in the NoSQL world, normalization is not as critical.  What you could do is to concatenate the key with the value in the sorted set.  So instead of `key: score`, you could store `key-value: score`. The `-` character can be any delimiter you choose so that you can easily parse. This saves you one trip to the `key: value` set to fetch the value. Again, it highly depends on the planned use of the sorted set.

Comment: Use would be to store the N most recently added pairs, like a queue where we could update the added at time for a key.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the use case. But even that, I don't see anything particularly wrong with your original approach. One thing worth mentioning is that, if you write the same piece of data to 2 places, you may want to bundle the 2 writes into one Redis transaction.  Such that either both writes succeed or both fail --you don't end up with inconsistent data.